# Jira Board is not showing issues from multiple projects

Tags: jira

I have created a jira board in which I want to show epics of multiple project that contain a value within the custom field `Objective`. For this I created the following filter:

```
type = Epic AND "Objective[Labels]" is not EMPTY ORDER BY created DESC
```

When I check the filter it is showing all the epics (from multiple projects) which have a value for Objective. When I use the filter within a board it is only showing the epics of one project.

***Update:***

There was a warning in the board configuration that certain states where not mapped. After dragging the unmapped states to the proper column the issues appeared. The states that I needed to map (todo, in-progress, etc) where the default ones for a project.

Must i map for every new project in which a epic with label `objectives` is created the states to the proper columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a warning in the board configuration that certain states were not mapped. After dragging the unmapped states to the proper column the issues appeared. The states that I needed to map (todo, in-progress, etc) were the default ones for a project.